# Exporting style file from Global Mapper

Tags: qgis, global-mapper

Does anyone know how to export a style file like QGIS qml or SLD format from Global Mapper? Gm is very good at importing files like .tab with styles preserved, but I cannot find a way to write these out in a format QGIS can understand.

Comment: Styles can be added to shapefile DB. Does that solve your problem? What kind of data are you trying to export and which styles you want to preserve?

Comment: Further to this, I found that Global Mapper worked in most instances but failed on several cases with large numbers of styles or where there was some overlap in stlyes. The GM team were very helpful in helping me resolve this. I understand the changes are now implemented in the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLobal Mapper supports exporting SLD - Style Layer Describer (Symbology Encoding) that can be imported into QGIS